# A splitted lstlisting environment between pages ignores some of tikz effects

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, page-breaking, atbegshi

I want to set a decorated page number packing in the the Tikz node with the use of `\AtBeginShipout` macro, but when a `lstlisting` environment with `basicstyle` option seting font to `\ttfamily` breaks between pages some of font features of the page number has no proper effect; in my example it's bold!

The following code shows the problem, and it'll be produced with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,]
            \node [draw, circle, color=gray, yshift=2cm] at (current page.south){\textbf{\LARGE\thepage}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lstset{ basicstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily\small,
    frameround=tftf,    frame=ltbr,}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{lstlisting}
print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The first page number isn't bold:

[image]

while the second one is OK (has bold face).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tikzpicture` seems to use the current font at the end of the page. At the end of your first page, the current font is `\ttfamily\small` (as specified in your `ltlisting` environment).

As workaround, you may add `\rmfamily` to your node (and use the `font` key):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,]
  \node [draw, circle, color=gray, yshift=2cm,font=\rmfamily\bfseries\Large]
  at (current page.south){\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lstset{ basicstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily\small,
    frameround=tftf,    frame=ltbr,}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{lstlisting}
print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')

print ('hello worlds')
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```